How to update GRUB after updating system, on Fedora, with NVMe SSD
The Fedora documentation on updating to a new Fedora release recommends that, after we update, we should update the GRUB bootloader.  They provide the following suggested advice on how to update:
$ sudo mount | grep "/boot "
/dev/sda4 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel)
$ sudo grub2-install /dev/sda

So for a disk that has a device name like /dev/sda, we are supposed to start with the partition device /dev/sda4, remove the number (4), and obtain /dev/sda.  However, my devices are numbered differently.  I have a NVMe SSD, and for me, /boot is on /dev/nvme0n1p2.
So it seems like the documentation is incomplete.  What should the correct instructions be, to handle this case?  How do I adapt these instructions, e.g., to systems with a NVMe SSD?
For example: What is the correct command to run? What parameter do I use with grub2-install?  Is grub2-install even the right command to run, or should I be running a different command?  Is it possible to give instructions that cover both the case of BIOS systems and UEFI systems?

@D.W. do you have a bios system or do you have a UEFI ?

@D'ArcyNader, UEFI -- but in the spirit of Stack Exchange and building an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, I'm thinking it might be best to seek an answer with instructions that work on all devices.  If you think that is too broad I'm open to revising the question to focus only on UEFI.

@D.W. the documentation says "Systems with the BIOS firmware have the GRUB RPM packages updated. However, the installed or embedded bootloader is never updated automatically. It is a good idea to update it between Fedora Linux release versions." it doesn't mention nothing to do on uefi system.

For SATA/SAS/USB/other kinds of storage, the common device node naming convention is /dev/sdXY, where X is a letter identifying the disk, and Y is a number identifying the partition.
NVMe drives use a different naming convention, which includes a namespace ID. Also, the device identifier is a number, not a letter. For non-enterprise NVMe storage, the namespace ID is normally always 1. So the naming convention can be considered to be /dev/nvmeXn1 for the whole-disk device, and /dev/nvmeXn1pY for partitions. The /dev/nvmeX device would refer to the NVMe controller specifically, and is only needed for some special functions, usually with the nvme command.
For the UEFI version of GRUB, the device containing the /boot directory is not as important as the device containing the EFI System Partition (ESP). In Fedora, ESP should normally be mounted at /boot/efi. If this convention is followed, specifying a disk device name for UEFI grub2-install is actually optional.
So you could update GRUB on your NVMe-based UEFI system this way:
$ sudo mount | grep "/boot/efi "
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (...various mount options...)
$ sudo grub2-install /dev/nvme0n1

But in practice, you should usually get away with just:
$ sudo grub2-install

and it will figure out the device to use on its own.
However: there are some UEFI-specific options you might want to use.

If you have just one OS installed on your system, and you want to have extra insurance that the system remains bootable even after a NVRAM reset/clearing of BIOS settings, then you might want to add the --force-extra-removable option to grub2-install command. (If you dual-boot with Windows, it will usually insist in placing a copy of its bootloader to the removable media position, for its "self-healing" feature.)

If your install is on a removable media and want to boot this removable media on other UEFI systems, you should add the --removable option.



For the UEFI version of GRUB, the device containing the /boot directory is not as important as the device containing the EFI System Partition (ESP). Which device contains /boot is not really relevant in either version. Even with the BIOS / i386-pc version, you can have the MBR boot code (and "core.img") on one drive and /boot on another drive.

Also, while I don't know if these days grub-install has been modified to attempt to "locate" a ESP mountpoint by some means when it decided / is instructed to install a EFI version and passed a dev node argument, there's the "old-school" --efi-directory switch, which in the past is required for EFI target installation, where you can simply passed the mountpoint of the ESP as an argument. (I mean, is there really just "heuristics" for the detection, or does the dev node passed really have an effect now in the decision making process?)
